# How to configure proguard to keep all classes in packages that contain a specific word in package name?

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation

I am trying to keep all classes in packages that contain the word *model* in the package name.

Eg - *com.xyz.**model**, com.xyz.abc.**model**, com.xyz.**model**.abc*

All the classes in these packages should not be obfuscated.

I tried using wildcard for package names but it isn't working

```
-keep class com.xyz.**.model.**{ *; }
```

How to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try below. Remove `dot(.)` before the model.

```
-keep class com.xyz.**model.**{ *; }
```

Comment: if it worked, upvote the answer it will be helpful for other users.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the reply. In addition, I am getting issues that proguard is renaming interface and class with the same name `public class c implements c` which is causing bean creation error in autowired fields. Any suggestions to fix that?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't hear such an issue. I will update if I get any idea on this. Thanks